# Kartik DateRangePicker

Tags: yii2

¿Estoy haciendo una vista para descargar los datos de una estación meteorológica y he puesto un kartik date range picker. Quisiera saber como puedo aumentar el rango de fechas que se puede seleccionar, ya que solo me permite seleccionar como máximo un rango de fechas de 1 año?

Comment: Siempre pon el código de lo que has intentado para darte un mejor resultado

Comment: no deberias tener ningun limite de fecha, http://demos.krajee.com/date-range prueba las demos

Comment: en los demos tambien sucede que si cambio la fecha inicial la final se cambia automaticamente o si cambio la fecha final la inicial se cambia sola